# Entity-framework System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I built this sample to help example my problem related to navigation properties to insert related entities. I am getting the error Error System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source' because of student2 not having data for course.

> Is there a way to insert this data and not get this error?

````
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Course = new Course();
            Course.Id = 1;
            Course.studentID = 1;
            Course.Name = "Math";

            var student1 = new student();
            student1.Id = 1;
            student1.Name = "Sam";
            student1.Courses.Add(Course);

            var student2 = new student();
            student2.Id = 2;
            student2.Name = "Bill";


        }
    }

    public class student
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int studentID { get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }
}```

Saving data


```var newStudent = db.Student
                          .Include(x => x.Course);

            var newInsertStudent = new EFModel.Student
                        {
                            Id = s.id,
                            Name = s.Name,
                            Courses = s.Courses.Select(p => new EFModel.Course
                            {
                                Id = p.Id,
                                studentID = s.id,
                                Name = s.name
                            }).ToList()
                        };   
             newStudent.Student.Add(newInsertStudent);```
````

Comment: It would seem that your issue is that you do not have any courses for Student2.  Are you trying to add him without being enrolled in courses?  Perhaps what you need is an empty list of courses. It seems your Courses list is never initialized.  Honestly, I'm a little surprised that it's not throwing an exception when you're trying to add a course to Sam.

Comment: Yes I am trying to add student2 without any courses the error is coming from Courses.Select(p => because it null why would I need a empty list of courses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: add a ? after s.Courses... this will make it not attempt to call into Select if Courses is null

```
var newInsertStudent = new EFModel.Student
                        {
                            Id = s.id,
                            Name = s.Name,
                            Courses = s.Courses?.Select(p => new EFModel.Course
                            {
                                Id = p.Id,
                                studentID = s.id,
                                Name = s.name
                            }).ToList()
                        };
```